# Image processing with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to show picture in codeigniter.  Either one or few pictures that I store in the gallery.

**gallery_model.php**

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_picture($pic_unique_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('galleries_pictures', $pic_unique_id);
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**controllers/cspages.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->gallery_model();
    $this->load->get_picture($pic_unique_id);
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

**views/index.php**

```
<?php foreach($pic as $pic_item) { ?>
<?php endforeach; } ?>
<!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/images/slider/1.jpg">
```

**How to get the $pic_unique_id and $pic_item ?**

Comment: Look at this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: And https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 1):

Try This IN **model**:

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_picture($pic_unique_id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('galleries_pictures',array('pic_id'=> $pic_unique_id));
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

IN **Controller**:

```
public function index()
{
   $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('gallery_model');//loads model
    $data['pic']  = $this->gallery_model->get_picture($pic_unique_id);//calls to model function
    $this->load->view('index',$data);//loads view with data
}
```

IN **view**

```
<?php foreach($pic as $pic_item) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url(assets1/images/slider/).$pic_item->pic_item; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in gallery_model.php

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model {
public function get_picture($pic_unique_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('galleries_pictures',array('pic_id'=>   $pic_unique_id));
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

Try this in controllers/cspages.php

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->gallery_model();
    $data['pic'] = $this->load->get_picture($pic_unique_id);
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

in views/index.php

```
<?php foreach($pic as $pic_item) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets1/images/slider/<?= $pic_item->pic_item ?> ">
<?php endforeach; } ?>
```